# How to write htaccess rewrite rule for this case? (with get parameters)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

please, help with the regex htaccess rule to make it possibe to redirect the following url:

http://hack-games-cheats-mobile1.info/haw/oh/index.html?name=Empire+Four+Kingdoms+Hack&img=https://mobile-cheats24.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/post-1-817x320.jpg

to

this

http://hack-games-cheats-mobile1.info/oh/index.html?name=Empire+Four+Kingdoms+Hack&img=https://mobile-cheats24.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/post-1-817x320.jpg

I need regex solution that is capable of redirecting the url whether it contains /haw/ or /de/, so it is /.*/ I suppose

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=[^&]+&img=[^&]+
RewriteRule ^/?(haw|de)/oh/index.html$ /oh/index.html [R,L]
```

It redirects when the url contains the query params `name` and `img`, and the request url prefix with `/haw/oh/index.html` or `/de/oh/index.html`. The destination url is `/oh/index.html`